# JW player dock button not scaling related to player scaling

Tags: php, flash, jwplayer

There is problem in scaling of Dock Buttons when of jw player when the player is resized. Here the Url of an example to see the issue.

http://clients.dbglab.com/player.html

Is there any way that I the dock button will automatically get re-sized relative to the size of the player?

Regards
Deepu

Comment: what do you mean by Dock Buttons? It seems resized properly here, only thing I can see is that the ratio of the player is kind of odd. At least they're not both 4:3 for example.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response.. Dock Item means the plugoin buttons in the player like Embed, HD, CC etc.. I wan a way to get it scaling according to the size of the player. If not, I want to place them at the control bar. Is there any way to implement this.? Please let me know if you need any further clarificaiton>

Comment: as I can see from the source these videos are included from another site. So IF there would be a chance to rescale the buttons that would be only if you get a player yourself and load the videosource in your own player. Right now you are limited to the video StoryBridge.TV supplies to you.

Comment: Yes, we actually have the source code of the player and the example I gave you was just to show how embed code appears.. We are looking for a solution to keep the icons on the control bar.. Is there any way for such implementation? FOllowing is the url of a video in our live site. 
http://storybridge.tv/StoryBridge/freespirits/story/fightclub

Comment: My guess is that the icons are somewhere described in the .swf/.fla source code. If so there's less you can do unless you are able to edit the source. Since you are able to skin JWPlayer this is your only option I assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the issue resolved by placing dock buttons on the control bar.

It was achieved by simply setting the dock variable "false"

s1.addVariable("dock",'false');

You can see the way it works at http://storybridge.tv/StoryBridge/freespirits/story/fightclub

Even though I got the solution, I just thought of sharing as it may help someone with similar need.

Answer (score 4):

Even though the Dock button is not on the control bar, you can resize the image, just by changing the size of the icon image.. Just make sure that the image size doesn't go beyond the button text.

Answer (score 4):

Even if we reduce the size of the image, it will not get resized according to the size of the player. Hope it is the actual requirement, but here the icon remains in the same size even if you increase the player size.